# jQuery tablesorter don't work

Tags: php, jquery, tablesorter

The table is diplayed normal but can not sort it.
Both .js files are in the same directory as the .php file itself.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabel").tablesorter();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$con = pg_connect("user=bct password=bct host=localhost port=5432 dbname=users ") or die (pg_last_error());
$query = "SELECT * from users";
$result = pg_query($con, $query);


$t = '<table id="tabel" class="tablesorter">';

$t .= '<thead>';
//next code get column names
for($i=0; $i < pg_num_fields($result); $i++){
    $field_info = pg_field_name($result, $i);
    $t .= '<th>' . $field_info .  '</th>';
}
$t .= '</thead>';


//next code fetch cell content
$t .= '<tbody>';

while ($row=pg_fetch_row($result)){
    $t .= '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $_column){
    $t .= '<td>' .$_column. '</td>';
    $temp=$row;
    }
    $t .= '</tr>';
}

$t .= '</tbody></table>';

echo $t;

pg_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"#tabel"` should be spelled table

Comment: Typo or not, it *does* match the id of the table itself. Not the problem.

Comment: And tablesortel is for tablesorter???

Comment: Also not usually a good idea to leave usernames and passwords in what you post.

Comment: You have to love three down votes with no explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
$t .= '<thead><tr>';
//next code get column names
for($i=0; $i < pg_num_fields($result); $i++){
    $field_info = pg_field_name($result, $i);
    $t .= '<th>' . $field_info .  '</th>';
}
$t .= '</tr></thead>';
```

I basically wrapped your `<th>`'s in a `<tr>`, going off of the example code here: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. What do you want to do?

Comment: When I put the <table border=1> the sorting doesn't work any more.

Comment: What if you use CSS to add a border?

Comment: How can I insert an index column with numbered rows at the begining of the table using tablesorter plugin? Thank you.